# Android Context Leak in VolleyInstance

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I recently used Volley library implemented as a singleton pattern. I referred to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton) implementation on google's developer training page :

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

If someone instantiated the above singleton as

`RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this).
    getRequestQueue();`

It would still lead to `mCtx`to leak since it is declared static.

Shouldn't they just change the implementation of Singleton to:

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context.getApplicationContext()); // <--Already using application context
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx);
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

Here I have changed `mInstance = new MySingleton(context);` to `mInstance = new MySingleton(context.getApplicationContext());`

My question is: Why leave it to users to send the application context? Why not safeguard within this class? Any thoughts?

Comment: The implementation in developers site is all good, the only thing you have to do is always send application context to it, not activity context.

Comment: That's the point. Why leave it to users to send the application context? Why not safeguard within this class?

Comment: If you use application context as static, memory leak won't occur because application context exists through out the app.

Comment: That is not my question. My question is more of design issue. Here, the class designer(MySingleton) wants that the user of this class should send application context. I am just saying that wouldn't it be better if we removed that ask and converted all contexts to application context?

Comment: If you do not want to pass context whenever you call get instance, then set application context once in your Application class.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to create it using the APPLICATION context:

```
RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).
getRequestQueue();
```

Since the Application context existsthe whole time of the application lifecycle it can not cause a memory leak.

Comment: That's the point I am referring to. Why leave it to users to send the application context? Why not safeguard within this class and always use application context?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use **Application** Context but beyond that there is nothing much to do, remember that `Context` exists as long as app is running.. So you can't really leak **Context**. You can try to get Context from `ApplicationController` in Your app but still it's all the same regarding Context:

```
private MySingleton() {
    mCtx = ApplicationController.getContext();
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    ...
```

and in your **Application** `class` define `getContext()` like this:

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }

    ...
```